# Сохранение mp3 потока

Tags: android

Есть некий mp3 поток. Возможно ли реализовать запись (сохранение) этого потока в mp3 файл на телефоне? Т.е. Нажали кнопку "Записать" начал сохранять, нажали "Стоп" остановил запись потока. Скиньте пожалуйста пример реализации данного функционала, гугл не помог мне в этом

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490608/how-to-implement-inapp-download-mp3-file